# Chrome Memory Leak with moving SVG text and blur filter

Tags: google-chrome, svg, memory-leaks, blur, svg-filters

I have a page with several SVG elements and each of them has an SVG Blur filter applied to it. I noticed that Chrome was running out of memory quickly if the elements keep moving continuously.

To reproduce check this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZJMVz

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>

  <svg height="0" width="0">
        <defs>      
            <filter id="f1">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
    </svg>
</head>

<body>  
    <svg height="30" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; width: 1000px;height: 500px;">
      <text x="0" y="15" fill="black" id="t0">BLUR TEST!</text>
    </svg>
    <script>
    (function() {
        var svgText = document.getElementById('t0');
        svgText.setAttribute('filter', 'url(#f1)');
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;

        setInterval(function(){
            x+=1;
            y+=1;

            if(x > 1000) {
                x = 0;
            }

            if( y > 500) {
                y = 0;
            }
            svgText.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')');
        }, 100);
    })();   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Open Chrome's Task Manager and notice memory usage by that tab. I filed a bug report on Chromium's Issue tracker. But wondering if anybody has run into this before and if there's a work around to this.

Thanks!

*edit*: Noticing this issue on Chrome 48.0.2564.97 m on Windows 7.